# Scala trait inheritance strange behavior

Tags: scala, traits

Can someone explain why is this program printing a 0 instead of 4?

```
trait Rectangular {
  def width: Int
  def height: Int
  val area = width * height
}
case class Square(val size: Int) extends Rectangular {
  val width = size
  val height = size
}

print(Square(2).area)
```

but it works when I make the vals lazy

```
trait Rectangular {
  def width: Int
  def height: Int
  val area = width * height
}
case class Square(val size: Int) extends Rectangular {
  lazy val width = size
  lazy val height = size
}

print(Square(2).area)
```

Comment: It is because you are defining area as a `val`. Use `def` and it will work.

Comment: the fact that it work with def or lazy val does not explain this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate issue with the way Scala constructs `val` members.

```
trait Rectangular {
  def width: Int
  def height: Int
  val area = width * height
}
case class Square(val size: Int) extends Rectangular {
  val width = size
  val height = size
}
```

Here, internally, Scala makes private members in `Square` called `width` and `height`. It initializes them to zero. Then, in the `Square` constructor, it sets them. Basically, it does something close to this Java code.

```
public abstract class Rectangular {
    private int area;
    public Rectangular() {
        area = width() * height();
    }
    public abstract int width();
    public abstract int height();
    public int area() { return area; }
}
public class Square extends Rectangular {
    private int width, height;
    public Square(int size) {
        Rectangular();
        width = size;
        height = size;
    }
    public int width() { return width; }
    public int height() { return width; }
}
```

Note that the `Rectangular` constructor is called before the `Square` constructor, so `area` sees the default zero `width` and `height` values before they're ever set. As you've already discovered, using `lazy val` fixes the problem.

```
trait Rectangular {
  def width: Int
  def height: Int
  val area = width * height
}
case class Square(val size: Int) extends Rectangular {
  lazy val width = size
  lazy val height = size
}
```

Alternatively, you can use early initializer syntax to force the values to be written in the right order.

```
trait Rectangular {
  def width: Int
  def height: Int
  val area = width * height
}
case class Square(val size: Int) extends {
  val width = size
  val height = size
} with Rectangular
```

The `lazy val` solution is usually preferable, as it leads to fewer surprises down the road.

For more information, see the [Scala FAQ](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html) about this particular topic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the val in your trait gets initialized before the vals from your class.

So when you call the constructor, first `area` gets initialized.  It sets its value as `width * height`.  Neither `width` nor `height` have been initialized yet so their value is zero.  This means `area = 0 * 0 = 0`.

After that, `width` and `height` get set to the value of `size`, but it's too late for area at this point.

It works with `lazy val` because lazy vals check to see if they have been initialized when accessed, and initialize themselves if not.  A regular val has no such checks.